# I tried to use intent email in my small android project but its not working. Can anyone help me to find the error?

Tags: java, android, email, android-intent

public void submit_order(View view) {                                //For ORDER button
EditText name_var = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
field = name_var.getText().toString();

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);                // only email apps should handle this
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Just Java order for " + field);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    display_message(field, number_of_coffee);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Add the email address in the mailto string, sir.